# Single keystroke for a series of keys

Tags: autohotkey

Lately I have been trying to remap my **LeftControl** button to perform "**wdwdwd**", this is how Meepo works for me. I had tried this piece of code

```
 <^:: Send, wdwdwd
```

the ahk file gets executed, but when i press left control i dont see wdwdwd on notepad.

Comment: Have you proven that it works with a simple key such as "a"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modifier `^` works for key combinations, what I believe you want is

`LCtrl::Send wdwdwd`

That sets up the left ctrl key press